# PDFBOX printing of document with bufferedimage fails

Tags: java, pdfbox

Obviously, none of this is blurred irl...

I start out with a blank document which you see below here:

[image: Original document]

I have a user give me an account number and the form gets populated. A window pops up and gets a signature. It creates the document you see here:

[image: Filled in document]

---

I can save this document and pull it up in adobe and it is formatted and I can see the signature, can print it out, yadda yadda. However, if I attempt to print it from my application I get this:

[image: Bad printout document]

For comparison, here is the code I use to save it:

```
contentStream.close(); // type PDPageContentStream containing a page of the overlayDoc
mergedDoc = overlayObj.overlay(overlayDoc, originalDoc); // overlayObj is of type Overlay. Docs are of type PDDocument
mergedDoc.save(someFileName);
```

And this is the code I am attempting to use to print it:

```
contentStream.close(); // same as above
mergedDoc = overlayObj.overlay(overlayDoc, originalDoc); // same as above
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); // java.awt.print.PrinterJob
mergedDoc.print(printJob);
```

My understanding is that the print method of a PDDocument takes a PrinterJob object and prints to that. A document is being printed, but it doesn't have the signature field correct. It's just a black box. I have also tried to save this as an image, which it does, but when I attempt to print the image I get the same issue.

Again, I can open this saved file and it does not have the box. When I am viewing it on the screen it doesn't have that black box. It is only there when I attempt to print it. Everything else works out correctly.

Any guesses where I should start? I've worked on this one for the better part of a day w/o success.

Comment: 1) what PDFBox version? 2) "I have also tried to save this as an image, which it does" does this mean then when viewing the image, there is no black box?

Comment: @Tim I am already away from the office, but the version should be current. I got the package less than a month ago. When I tried to print the bufferedimage that PDPage.convertToImage() offers, the image once again would have that black box. Really strange here, bit I use that same method to display the page on the screen and it has no issues. It seems to happen in the print method for  PDDocument.

Comment: Is it a 1.8.x release version or a 2.0.0 development version snapshot? Rendering is much improved in 2.0.0.

Comment: Try https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ and run the latest jar and use PDFReader or PDFToImage parameter and then your file to see if it is better with 2.0. Nevertheless I wonder what's going on there, the 1.8 version usually fails with fonts.

Comment: This breaks so much of my code. I can't figure out how to take a bufferedimage and draw it onto the page now (for the signature itself). Before I could use the PDPixelMap class, but there is no such thing in 2.0. Any guesses how to take a bufferedimage and put it on the content stream? The method is .drawImage(PDFImageIObject, x, y) or .drawImage(PDInlineImage, x, y). How do I put that bufferedimage in the stream now?

Comment: @blahfunk see the LosslessFactory class in 2.0, this replaces the PDPixelMap class. Don't worry, it does accept BufferedImages.