# Using Overlay in PDFBox 2.0

Tags: java, pdfbox

What I am trying to do here is to create text and place it onto a blank page. That page would then be overlayed onto another document and that would then be saved as one document. In 1.8 I was able to create a blank PDPage in a PDF, write text to it as needed, then overlay that PDF with another and then save or view on screen using the code below -

```
overlayDoc = new PDDocument();
page = new PDPage();
overlayDoc.addPage(page);
overlayObj = new Overlay();
font = PDType1Font.COURIER_OBLIQUE;
try {
    contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(overlayDoc, page);
    contentStream.setFont(font, 10);
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("content stream failed");
}
```

After I created the stream, when I needed to write something to the overlay document's contentStream, I would call this method, give it my x, y coords and tell it what text to write (again, this is in my 1.8 version):

```
protected void writeString(int x, int y, String text) {
    if (text == null) return;
    try {
        contentStream.moveTo(x, y);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.drawString(text);  // deprecated. Use showText(String text)
        contentStream.endText();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(text + " failed. " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

I would call this method whenever I needed to add text and to wherever I needed to do so. After this, I would close my content stream and then merge the documents together as such:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.Overlay;
Overlay overlayObj = new Overlay();

....

PDDocument finalDoc = overlayObj.overlay(overlayDoc, originalDoc);
```

*finalDoc* now contains a PDDocument which is my original PDF with text overlayed where needed. I could save it and view it as a BufferedImage on the desktop. The reason I moved to 2.0 was that first off I needed to stay on top of the most recent library and also that I was having issues putting an image onto the page (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771489/pdfbox-printing-of-document-with-bufferedimage-fails)).

The issue I am having in this question is that 2.0 no longer has something similar to the `org.apache.pdfbox.Overlay` class. To confuse me even more is that there are two Overlay classes in 1.8 ([org.apache.pdfbox.Overlay](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/Overlay.html) and [org.apache.pdfbox.util.Overlay](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/Overlay.html)) whereas in 2.0 there is only one. The class I need (`org.apache.pdfbox.Overlay`), or the methods it offers at least, are not present in 2.0 as far as I can tell. I can only find [org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Overlay](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/Overlay.html).

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, i.e. did your code work, are you asking before trying anything? Please look at the source code of OverlayPDF.java for5 an example: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/OverlayPDF.java?view=markup&sortby=date

Comment: I am sorry... No, the code did not work. I already have the two documents. I think that the way I am using my writeString method should be putting text in the contentStream. I should be able to close that contentStream and then merge the originalDoc and overlayDoc together to get a new PDDocument, but when I try to display this as an image I just get the original document.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr When I look at the code supplied it is merging two files together. I have the PDF's loaded already as PDDocuments. I need to overlay one over the other. The `overlay(Map<Integer,String> specificPageOverlayFile)` is what is getting me bcz it needs a file to overlay?

Comment: "the code did not work" is not very specific. The best would be to rework your question, to show a complete minimal code in 1.8, and a complete code in 2.0, and an explanation what happens. With these two pieces of software I could investigate this.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr... Updated.

Comment: Done. Suggestion: change your title to something like "Using Overlay in PDFBox 2.0", as your question isn't really about a page content stream problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some quick code that works, it adds "deprecated" over a document and saves it elsewhere:

```
    PDDocument overlayDoc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    overlayDoc.addPage(page);
    Overlay overlayObj = new Overlay();
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER_OBLIQUE;

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(overlayDoc, page);
    contentStream.setFont(font, 50);
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(200, 200);
    contentStream.drawString("deprecated");  // deprecated. Use showText(String text)
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();

    PDDocument originalDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("...inputfile.pdf"));
    overlayObj.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.FOREGROUND);
    overlayObj.setInputPDF(originalDoc);
    overlayObj.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(overlayDoc);
    Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); // empty map is a dummy
    overlayObj.setOutputFile("... result-with-overlay.pdf");
    overlayObj.overlay(ovmap);
    overlayDoc.close();
    originalDoc.close();
```

What I did additionally to your version:

- declare variables
- close the content stream
- set a color
- set to foreground
- set a text position (not a stroke path position)
- add an empty map

And of course, I read the [OverlayPDF source code](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/OverlayPDF.java?view=markup&sortby=date), it shows more possibilities what you can do with the class.

Bonus content:

Do the same without using the Overlay class, which allows further manipulation of the document before saving it.

```
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER_OBLIQUE;
    PDDocument originalDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("...inputfile.pdf"));
    PDPage page1 = originalDoc.getPage(0);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(originalDoc, page1, true, true, true);
    contentStream.setFont(font, 50);
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(200, 200);
    contentStream.drawString("deprecated");  // deprecated. Use showText(String text)
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();
    originalDoc.save("....result2.pdf");
    originalDoc.close();
```

Comment: I did not word my question correctly and I will when I get back to the office in a few hours, but the source code you showed me was fine except that after I overlay the document I not ready go save it yet. I want to view it but I may not want to save it yet. I am bad at wording questions so I apologize. Your work on this question and the pdfbox package is very much appreciated.

Comment: The current implementation does not have an option to return a PDDocument object. I wasn't involved there, i.e. didn't read the issues, so I don't know their motivation. However there are other easy ways to work without using the overlay class, you could simply add a new content stream to an existing PDPage (use the constructor with five parameters, nr. 3 and 5 should be true).

Comment: I added an example that shows what I meant in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't get the role of Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); here. whats the point of using ovmap  ??

Comment: @farhad Sorry for the confusion, it is a dummy, see the javadoc: "The map must be empty (but not null) if no specific mappings are used". I have included a comment.

Comment: Code look similar to mine but I have another more qustion for you: I'm trying to do the same with Pdf/A-3B file but I normally break the A-3B compliance applying overlay. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: The code above doesn't embed fonts, maybe that is the problem. Use `PDType0.load()` to get an embedded font. You need to save the overlay document first or the embedding / subsetting won't be there.

Comment: Note that in current versions of PDFBox (2.0.28) the method setOutputFile in Overlay no longer exists. Instead Overlay.overlay(...) returns a new PDDocument which you then have to save.