# Apache PDFBox merge two pages into one

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have two PDF files, one containing text (also available in RTF format) and one containing a background image. Now, I'd like to merge those two pages into one by putting the text pdf above the background pdf.

One solution I came across was to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23327024/3755692) to convert the pdf files to images and draw them onto a new page. However, I wonder if this is the best solution since the PDF won't contain any text afterwards that you could copy&paste but just images.

Is there a solution to merge two pages without converting them to images first?

Comment: *"I wonder if this is the best solution"* - it certainly isn't. You should look at the `Overlay` class as used for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32844926/1729265).

Comment: The fact that it is a bad solution doesnt mean it cant be the best available. But your link sounds good, Ill try that